# Как быстро создать пустой и непустой текстовый файл в Linux через терминал?

Tags: linux

Как быстро создать пустой и непустой текстовый файл в Linux через терминал?

Comment: самый быстрый способ создать файл это fallocate.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> Ответ общий, вы можете исправить его, если считаете нужным.

Существует N-ое количество способов создания текстовых файлов, мы приведём два основных, которые, на наш взляд, самые быстрые с точки зрения клавиатурного ввода, и несколько других.

> Под фразой «при вводе» подразумевается, что нужно ввести команду в терминал и нажать клавишу `Enter`.

---

### Создание пустых файлов

```
> a
```

При вводе этой команды в текущей директории будет создан пустой файл с именем `a`.

Можно вводить без пробела:

```
>a
```

Более читаемый вариант, помогает не ошибиться и не записать случайно результат предыдущей команды в файл:

```
: > file
```

(NOP > file).

Можно создать сразу сколь угодно файлов:

```
> b > c > d > e > f > g
```

Хотя так удобней (о `touch` будет далее):

```
touch b c d e f g
```

---

### Создание файлов с текстом

```
echo blablabla > h
```

При вводе этой команды в текущей директории будет создан файл с именем `h`, содержащий текст `blablabla` и *один перевод строки*.

Можно вводить без пробела вокруг оператора `>`:

```
echo blablabla>i
```

---

Выводимый контекст можно заключить в кавычки, а можно и не заключать, даже если он содержит пробелы:

```
echo bla bla bla > j
echo 'bla bla bla' > k
echo "bla bla bla" > l
```

Все три вышеперечисленные команды дают одинаковый результат (кроме имён файлов, естественно).

---

Также можно провернуть такую штуку:

```
echo 123 > m > n > o
```

При вводе этой команды в текущей директории будут созданы два пустых файла: `m` и `n`; и файл `o`, содержащий текст `123` и *один перевод строки*.

---

Иными словами, результат всех команд, которые что-нибудь выводят, можно запихнуть в файл ...

```
man man > p
```

Ман по `man`'у ... При вводе этой команды в текущей директории будет создан файл с именем `p`, содержащий мануал по команде `man`.

---

```
cal 2000 > 2000
```

Календарик на 2000 год ...

---

### Другие способы создания файлов

#### Создание пустого файла с помощью [`touch`](//google.com/search?q=touch+%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0)

```
touch q
```

При вводе этой команды в текущей директории будет создан пустой файл с именем `q`.

> Если быть точным, то touch это команда, основное назначение которой изменить время последнего изменения или последнего доступа файла, если же файл не существует, то она создает его. [Цитата](http://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=92142.0).

#### Создание файла «с текстом» с помощью [`cat`](//google.com/search?q=cat+%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0)

```
cat > r
```

При вводе этой команды в текущей директории будет создан пустой файл с именем `r` и терминал перейдёт в режим конкатенации вводимых строк к концу содержимого этого файла. То есть мы можем сразу же начать заполнять файл текстом. Сохранение набранного текста будет происходит построчно по нажатию клавиши `Enter`. Иными словами, по нажатию клавиши `Enter` будет выполняться [конкатенация](//google.com/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F).

Можно вводить без пробела:

```
cat>s
```

#### Пример

- Вводим `cat>s` — в текущей директории создан пустой файл с именем `s`.
- Набираем `123` — этого текста ещё не будет в файле.
- Нажимаем `Enter` — текст `123` записался в файл и курсор, как в терминале, так и в файле, перешёл на новую строку.

На строку выше вернуться нельзя.

Выйти из режима конкатенации можно с помощью `Ctrl+D` (EOF — End Of File) в начале строки. Если вы уже начали набирать строку, `Ctrl+D` не закончит ввод файла, но запишет набранную часть строки *без* символа конца строки. Так вы можете записывать строки частями. Для выхода с незавершённой строкой можно нажать `Ctrl+D` дважды, тогда последняя строка в файле не будет иметь символа конца строки (EOL — End Of Line).

---

#### Создание файла с помощью редактора.

Очевидно, что мы можем исользовать редактор типа `nano`, `vi`, `vim`, etc для создания файла.

**Пример**

1. Вводим `nano t` — открывается редактор `nano` в терминальном режиме.
2. Вводим `123` и нажимаем `Ctrl + O` (не ноль, а буква), а затем `Enter` — в текущей директории создался файл с именем `t`, содержащий текст `123` и *один перевод строки*.
3. Чтобы выйти и редактора нажимаем `Ctrl + X` (внизу редактора подсказки).

---

#### Создание файла с данными через dd

Полезно иногда создавать файл определенного размера с нулями

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=./file bs=10M count=100
```

или случайными байтами

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=./file bs=10M count=100
```

Создается файл из 100 блоков по 10 мегабайт - 1 ГБ.

#### Выделение места под файл средствами файловой системы

Такие команды работают быстерее dd потому как сами данные не записываются, а просто выделяется область диска

```
fallocate -l 10M ./file
```

или

```
truncate -s 10M ./file
```

fallocate резервирует место под файл на диске, а truncate обрезает файл или добавляет до нужного размера, резервируя место на диске.

При создании файлов таким образом в них могут содержаться куски удаленных рание файлов на некоторых системах.